# Using Jquery / Ajax and writting POST response text to a div layer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I'm not a jquery expert, and for the last 6 hours I been trying to get this to work.

I need to send 2 radio button groups and 1 array of checkboxes through ajax to get the html response from my php page.

I have verified the processing php page is working correctly by adding a form / button and actually posting the form data, but I want to get it on the fly and stick it in the response div.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

The HTML:

```
<div class="formtaglong">
             <input type="radio" value="both" name="buildings" class="small_radio" checked > <span class="checkboxText">Both</span> 
             <input type="radio" value="thunder" name="buildings" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Thunderhawk</span> 
             <input type="radio" value="center" name="buildings" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Center Drive</span> 
             </div>

 <div class="formtaglong" id="checkall">
              <input type="checkbox" value="All" id="sa" name="sa" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">All</span>
             <?php
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                 echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['operator'].'" name="users[]" class="small_radio"> <span class="checkboxText">' .$row['operator'] . '</span> ';
             }
             ?>
             </div>
<div class="formtaglong">
             <input type="radio" id="alltime" value="alltime" name="daterange" class="small_radio" checked ><span class="checkboxText">All</span>
             <input type="radio" id="today" value="today" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Today</span>
             <input type="radio" id="yesterday" value="yesterday" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Yesterday</span>
             <input type="radio" id="threedays" value="threedays" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">3 Days</span>
             <input type="radio" id="thisweek" value="thisweek" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">This Week</span>
             <input type="radio" id="thismonth" value="thismonth" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">This Month</span>
             <input type="Submit" name="print" id="print" value="Submit" class="button">
             </div>

 <div id="results" class="shadeGood" style="max-height:620px; width:778px; overflow:auto; float:left;">
<!-- I SHOULD HOLD RESPONSE DATA -->
             </div>
```

This is the jquery function I have thus far

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#main").click(function() {

                    //check radio buildings for selected value
                    var radBuild = $('input:radio[name=buildings]:checked').val();

                    //check radio daterange for selected value
                    var radDate = $('input:radio[name=daterange]:checked').val();

                    //create array for multiple possibilites from checkbox users
                    var chkUsers = [];
                    //loop through checkboxes appending values to array
                    $('#checkall :checked').each(function() {
                       chkUsers.push($(this).val());
                     });

                     //send the request
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/pick-print-results.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: "buildings=" + radBuild + "&daterange=" + radDate + "&users[]=" + chkUsers,
                        // callback for success
                        success: function(data){
                        $("results").html(data); 
                        } //ends sucess callback function
                    }); //ends .ajax function
                 }); //end #checkall.click function
              }); // ends ready function
                    </script>
```

I should note currently all the input div layers are nested in a div id#main and I'm only using the click function for testing.

EDIT: 
By Request Adding php processing file:...
Note.. I did not bother sanitizing results because this webpage is only going to be used internally off network.

```
<?php
//Break up Refer on forward slash /
$refer =explode('/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

//IF Request Page not print-picks.php page then bounce them there...
if (end($refer)!='print-picks.php') {
      $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
      $uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
      $extra = 'print-picks.php';
      header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
      exit();
}
include 'connect_to_db.php';
require_once ('doctype.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['daterange'])){ $daterange = $_POST['daterange']; }else{$daternage='';}
if(isset($_POST['users'])) { $users=$_POST['users']; }else{ $users='';}
if(isset($_POST['buildings'])){ $buildings=$_POST['buildings']; }else{$buildings='';}

//Build Daterange AND statment for query
switch ($daterange) {
    case "alltime":
    $query_chunk_2='';
    break;
    case "today":
    $query_chunk_2= 'AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d') . '\'';
    break;
    case "yesterday":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    case "threedays":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-3 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    case "thisweek":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    case "thismonth":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-30 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    default:
    $query_date='';
}

//Build Building AND Statment for query
switch ($buildings) {
    case "both":
    $query_chunk_3='';
    break;
    case "center":
    $query_chunk_3='AND l.building LIKE \'%Center%\'';
    break;
    case "thunder":
    $query_chunk_3='AND l.building LIKE \'%Thunder%\'';
    break;
    default:
    $query_chunk_3='';
}

//check if users is array
if(is_array($users)) {
//Deal With User Array
 //IF ALL IS SET..... GET ALL USERS IGNORE OTHER SELECTIONS
if($_POST['users'][0]=='All') {
    $query_chunk_4="AND  o.operator NOT LIKE ' '";
} else {
    //ELSE WE LOOP THROUGH EACH VALUE AND BUILD THE QUERY STATEMENT

    //Chunk 4 segment 1
    $query_chunk_4 ="AND o.operator IN(";

    //Get Total Array Values To Properly Add Commas to the String
    $i=0; // zero start value counter
    $ar_count=count($_POST['users']); //total elments in array
        foreach($_POST['users'] as $k=>$c)
        {
            $query_chunk_4.="'".$c."'";
            if($i!=$ar_count && $i!=($ar_count-1)){
                $query_chunk_4.=",";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        //Chunk 4 last segment
        $query_chunk_4 .=")";
}
}else { //USERS IS NOT AN ARRAY
$query_chunk_4="AND  o.operator NOT LIKE ' '";
}

//STATIC BEGINING OF QUERY
$query_chunk_1="SELECT pi . * , p.part_number, o.description, l.location, r.received_date
FROM picks AS pi
INNER JOIN parts AS p ON p.part_id = pi.part_id
INNER JOIN operators AS o ON o.operator_id = pi.operator_id
INNER JOIN locations AS l ON l.location_id = pi.location_id
INNER JOIN received AS r ON r.received_id = pi.received_id
WHERE pi.action_id = '11'";

//STATIC END OF QUERY
$query_chunk_last="ORDER BY pi.date_requested ASC";

//MERGE QUERY
$big_chunk_sql=$query_chunk_1 . ' ' . $query_chunk_2 . ' ' . $query_chunk_3 . ' ' . $query_chunk_4 . ' ' . $query_chunk_last;
$big_chunk_query=mysql_query($big_chunk_sql) or die(mysql_error());
//echo "<br> Big Chunk  = ".$big_chunk_sql;

        $i='';
        echo  '<table border="1px" style="width: 761px;" cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($big_chunk_query)) {
           if ($i%2 !=0)
             $rowColor = 'tr1center';
              else
             $rowColor = 'tr2center';
                $pendingdate= trim($data['received_date']);
                $newpendingdate = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($pendingdate));
                echo '<tr class="'.$rowColor.'"><td>'.$data['part_number'] . '</td><td>'.date("m-j-y, g:i a", strtotime($data['date_requested'])) .'</td><td>'
                .$data['description'].'</td><td>'. $data['qty_requested'] . '</td><td>'. $data['location'].'</td><td>'. $newpendingdate . '</td><td> 
                <a href="picking.php?radiopart='.urlencode($data['org_transaction_id']) .'">Mark Picked</a></td></tr>';
                if($data['notes_to_picker']!='') { 
                echo '<tr class="'.$rowColor.'" align="center"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td align="right"><b>notes:</b></td><td colspan="4">' . $data['notes_to_picker'].'</td></tr>';
                }
                $i++;
            }
            echo '</table></div>';
?>
```

EDIT #2 
I added an alert(data) to my success function and I"m getting back what looks like valid results, it however appears at this time not to be written to the results div layer.
Here is a popup of results I'm seeing from alert..

```
<table border="1px" style="width: 761px;" cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="tr2center"><td>AS001-70S</td><td>10-9-12, 9:42 am</td><td>Don Ford </td><td>500</td><td>LOAD</td><td>09-28-2010</td><td> 

                <a href="picking.php?radiopart=1005">Mark Picked</a></td></tr><tr class="tr1center"><td>H-016-V75</td><td>10-9-12, 11:28 am</td><td>Don Ford </td><td>80</td><td>LOAD</td><td>09-05-2012</td><td> 

                <a href="picking.php?radiopart=4503">Mark Picked</a></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: paste here php file also

Comment: what is the response you are getting/ should be getting?

Comment: thanks posted the php file so you should see what I expect to get back

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to put everything(html)  you will need inside a form and then just send   everything with $('form').serialize()

in your success method console.log( data ) or alert( data ) to see what you are getting

use

it depends if you want to retrieve just a value or array of values, in this case just send back json object.

open the java console in your browser to see if you are getting an error. it is gonna be easier.

and use in your ajax method: 
 data: { "postvar": $('some').val(), "other" : 'val' },

it was a quick answer  ;)

Comment: Not seeing any errors..
[09:11:50.004] GET http://localhost/inventory/print-picks.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 4ms]
[09:11:52.342] POST http://localhost/inventory/pick-print-results.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]
[09:11:55.625] POST http://localhost/inventory/pick-print-results.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]
--
[09:12:01.237] POST http://localhost/inventory/pick-print-results.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]
[09:12:02.491] POST http://localhost/inventory/pick-print-results.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]

Comment: mm try to see XHR response or set a error method in your ajax function like: error: function( xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError ){ alert( thrownError)}